# How can I automate looking up, filtering, and saving values in a new list/dataframe

Tags: r, automation

I have a larger dataset from which I computed different values. The interesting values are stored in dataframes within lists within lists. Now I want to automate looking up the interesting values and storing them in a handy way to perform further tasks (e.g. print out which units of analysis are of interest).

I am at a loss how to automate this tedious task, because placeholders don't work anymore - or none that I know of.

EXAMPLE:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)
set.seed(1234)
largelist <- list(
  Tab_USA_2001 = list(df = as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=10, min=1, max=20), nrow=5)), case = c(1)),
  Tab_CAN_1999 = list(df = as.data.frame(matrix(runif(n=10, min=1, max=20), nrow=5)), case = c(2))
)
```

I want to perform these two steps (but not only with two examples but many more):

```
Important_data <- list(TAB_USA_2001 = filter(largelist$Tab_USA_2001$df, V1 > 10),
                       TAB_CAN_1999 = filter(largelist$Tab_CAN_1999$df, V1 > 10)
                       )
flextable(Important_data$TAB_USA_2001)
flextable(Important_data$TAB_CAN_1999)
```

The data is always stored following this convention of

- Tab (for Table of Results from previous steps)
- XXX (Three letter code for the analyzed country)
- YYYY (Four numbers for the year of analysis)

Not all countries are analyzed for every year and there are only certain years in the analysis (e.g., 1991, 1999, 2001, 2003) which are not directly related.

Furthermore, I don't yet understand how I can access data that is buried deep in the list without typing the ...$...$... out everytime - shouldn't there be a way to make this easier. For example saying `largelist$[PLACEHOLDER]$df`

How could I create a loop/automation cycle that brings the interesting values from the Tables of Results together?

Comment: What is the gain of `Tab_USA_2001 = list(df = as.data.frame(...))`? In other words, why is a list of data frames not enough? For grabbing a structure like Tab, XXX, YYYY there are at least hundreds of sources available. What have you tried so far?

Comment: A hint to access elements of nested lists: try `lapply(names(largelist), \(x) largelist[[x]]$df) `.

Comment: @Friede I was trying to mimic the data structure of my objects. The interesting values are stored in a dataframe inside a list (with three other data frames applying to the same case but with different information) which is inside a list of all my results.

Thanks for the answers, I'll try to implement your answers ASAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `largelist` already has all your tables, here's a way to reshape your list into a data frame with each table name, its related data and `case` value, separated out for easier filtering and analysis.

```
enframe(largelist) |>
  unnest_wider(value) |>
  unnest(df) |>
  separate(name, c("Tab", "Country", "Year"), remove = FALSE) |>
  filter(V1 > 10)

# A tibble: 7 × 7
  name         Tab   Country Year     V1    V2  case
  <chr>        <chr> <chr>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Tab_USA_2001 Tab   USA     2001   12.8  1.18     1
2 Tab_USA_2001 Tab   USA     2001   12.6  5.42     1
3 Tab_USA_2001 Tab   USA     2001   12.8 13.7      1
4 Tab_USA_2001 Tab   USA     2001   17.4 10.8      1
5 Tab_CAN_1999 Tab   CAN     1999   14.2 16.9      2
6 Tab_CAN_1999 Tab   CAN     1999   11.4  6.44     2
7 Tab_CAN_1999 Tab   CAN     1999   18.5  4.55     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example, the two steps

(i) filter each data frame on the condition `V1 > 10L`, and

(ii) display as `flextable`,

can be performed as follows:

```
lapply(X = names(largelist), 
       FUN = \(i) {
         largelist[[i]]$df } |>
         { \(x) dplyr::filter(x, V1 > 10L)}() |> 
         flextable::flextable()
       )
```

An `R-base` approach to store *interesting results* in a single data frame:

```
do.call(what = "rbind", 
        args = lapply(X = names(largelist), 
                      FUN = \(i) {
                        cbind(largelist[[i]]$df, 
                              "df_name" =  rep(i, nrow(largelist[[i]]$df))
                              ) } |>
                        { \(x) x[x$V1 > 10L, ] }()
                      )
        )
```

gives

```
        V1        V2      df_name
1 12.82369  1.180419 Tab_USA_2001
2 12.57622  5.418460 Tab_USA_2001
3 12.84421 13.655591 Tab_USA_2001
4 17.35739 10.770772 Tab_USA_2001
5 14.17823 16.908617 Tab_CAN_1999
6 11.35452  6.438242 Tab_CAN_1999
7 18.54524  4.547733 Tab_CAN_1999
```

We loop over the names in `largelist` and add a column to each `df` called `df_name` for identification purposes. For each `df`, we subset
based on the condition `V1 > 10L`. With `do.call(what = "rbind", ...)` we row-bind the data frames to a single one.

You probably need to adapt to your data structure, as your toy data does not mimic the real data at hand. If speed is an issue, let me know. There are plenty of ways to increase speed. Even in `R base`.